# Error while deploying via anthill pro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, anthill

We use Anthill pro to deploy our code .Revision 6678 has been deployed in our DEV environment.Now, we have done some changes in the Code for 6678.We have committed the changes in SVN, this revision '6718' gets build successfully but throws an error while deploying. The error is below.The changes we have done are very minor changes which we are sure should not throw and error.

```
command line: E
command output: 

E:\_tmp\dev>setlocal

E:\_tmp\dev>set ENV=dev 

E:\_tmp\dev>set PROJECT=Gsk.Eureka.Web 

E:\_tmp\dev>set COMPONENT=Eureka 

E:\_tmp\dev>set IIS_SITE_PATH=E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka 

E:\_tmp\dev>set IIS_SITE_NAME=socrates-dev 

E:\_tmp\dev>set UNLOCKER_FILEPATH="D:\Program Files\Unlocker\Unlocker.exe" 

E:\_tmp\dev>set EUREKA_SOLUTION_HOME=E:\_tmp\dev\.tmp\WebApps\ 

E:\_tmp\dev>set EUREKA_CONFIG_FOLDER=E:\_tmp\dev\.config\dev-app01\Eureka 

E:\_tmp\dev>echo Publishing project Gsk.Eureka.Web to E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka 
Publishing project Gsk.Eureka.Web to E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka

E:\_tmp\dev>if not exist E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka (mkdir E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka ) 

E:\_tmp\dev>"D:\Program Files\Unlocker\Unlocker.exe" E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka /s 

E:\_tmp\dev>REM Delete everything, but the content of LocalData (keep the log files) 

E:\_tmp\dev>echo Deleting previous version 
Deleting previous version

E:\_tmp\dev>ATTRIB +H E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka\LocalData 

E:\_tmp\dev>FOR / %i IN ("E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka\*.*") DO (RD /S /Q "%i" ) 

E:\_tmp\dev>DEL /Q "E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka\*.*" 

E:\_tmp\dev>ATTRIB -H E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka\LocalData 

E:\_tmp\dev>echo Copying\Overriding web application files 
Copying\Overriding web application files

E:\_tmp\dev>xcopy /v /f /s /y /z /r E:\_tmp\dev\.tmp\WebApps\\Gsk.Eureka.Web\*.* E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka 
File not found - *.*
0 File(s) copied

E:\_tmp\dev>if errorlevel 1 (exit /b 1  ) 
===============================
command exit code: 1
```

We are getting another error in one of the build jobs despite the fact that the build is successful.

> E:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only>Build\publishArtifacts.bat
>   Gsk.Eureka.Web   Preparing to publish to
>   E:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Build\..\Artifacts\WEBAPPS\Gsk.Eureka.Web
>   Publishing project Gsk.Eureka.Web to
>   E:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Build\..\Artifacts\WEBAPPS\Gsk.Eureka.Web
>   e:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Gsk.Eureka.Web\App_Code\GskUserHelper.cshtml(2):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Gsk' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
>   e:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Gsk.Eureka.Web\App_Code\SearchResultHelper.cshtml(2):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Gsk' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
>   e:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Gsk.Eureka.Web\App_Code\SearchResultHelper.cshtml(3):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Gsk' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
>   e:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Gsk.Eureka.Web\App_Code\SearchResultHelper.cshtml(4):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Gsk' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
>   e:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Gsk.Eureka.Web\App_Code\GskUserHelper.cshtml(3):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GskUser' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
>   e:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Gsk.Eureka.Web\App_Code\SearchResultHelper.cshtml(5):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SearchResultViewModel' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) 
>   e:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Gsk.Eureka.Web\App_Code\SearchResultHelper.cshtml(135):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SearchResultViewModel' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) 
>   e:\anthill\agent\var\jobs\projects\Eureka\Build_only\Gsk.Eureka.Web\App_Code\SearchResultHelper.cshtml(244):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SearchResultViewModel' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)  ===============================  command exit code: 0

Can somebody please help ?

Comment: It would be nice if you can specify if the answer was OK or not. Isn't it all the purpose ? 
Its also helps improving the StackOverflow data

Answer (score 0):

The first error I see is "File not found" in it, I saw -

E:_tmp\dev>xcopy /v /f /s /y /z /r E:_tmp\dev.tmp\WebApps\\Gsk.Eureka.Web*.* E:\wwwroot\dev\Eureka

So I thought it us because you have two slashes '\\' in the path.

Comment: Editted my answer